# Looking for an efficient file caching system

Tags: java, file, caching, compression

I'm currently developing an MMO which utilizes numerous sprites (image files), and I plan to store these files in a compressed state on the user's hard drive.  I was wondering if there already exists an implementation of an efficient, directory-based cache system, in which I can utilize to store these image files in different folders that can compress into either one file or multiple files.  I was also researching LZ4 (de)compression, and I suppose that would be useful as well, but that does not solve the directory issue.

Thanks!

EDIT: For example, one file should hold numerous image files.

If something like this does not exist, what would the fastest way be to compress multiple image files into one file, and then decompress to load them into memory when the program starts?

Comment: Will a jar file do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It depends; what would the jar file contain?  I'd rather the user not have the option of viewing the contents of the file itself (e.g. if the jar file held uncompressed image files).

Comment: The jar file contains what you put in it.  The idea is to have an easy way to contain multiple files in a single file.  It is up to you to do whatever you want to do with the bytestream when read into memory.  In short, I don't think you can avoid having to do the grunt work yourself.    Much of this is just putting the right building blocks together - you will probably not find a finished solution

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I see, I guess what I'm looking for specifically is a method to compress multiple files into one file, and decompress that file when the program is run so it can be deserialized.  A jar file wouldn't really suffice because I wouldn't want the players having access to the image files.

Comment: Perhaps consider the [java.util.zip.ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) Class.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I'm not looking for something that can only be extracted using code and not an archive manager.